# Craft SeoMatic GTM <noscript> disable on 404 pages

Tags: craft3, plugin-seomatic

I want to disable google tag manager on 404 templates, I am able to add the additional condition for the script "Google Tag Manager Settings"
[image]

It has stopped GTM script code, but `<noscript>` tracking is still rendering on the page.

[image]

Is their way inside plugin options/SeoMatic template variable, soi can hide `<noscript>` code as well on specific pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SEOmatic author here -- what version of SEOmatic are you using? I think the best way to do this would be to just disable the container from being included in your 404 Twig template:

```
{% do seomatic.script.get('googleTagManager').include(false) %}
```

As per: https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-seomatic#google-tag-manager

Comment: I am using `3.1.23`, thank you for an answer, it's working well

Comment: Great! You can use that same technique for any containers or tags in SEOmatic